# Модальные окна

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Я хотел спросить, можно ли как-то убрать с модального окна кнопку закрытия (крестик в углу), то есть чтобы оно закрывалось нажатием какого-то баттона. Сам я пользуюсь плагином на jQuery - fancyBox, но в параметрах я такой функции не находил.

Если кто знает, как это реализовать помогите. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А тут, http://fancybox.net/api, в опциях есть showCloseButton - это не подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открываете firebug и кликаете по кнопке, берете и смотрите ее класс или id. Кнопка имеет id `fancybox-close` (посмотрел на демостраничке). И пишете через цсс ей `visibility:hidden` (для скрытия элементов можно использовать `display:none`, но с `fancybox` это не сработает, т.к. скрипт навешивает закрывающему элементу `display:inline` на атрибут `style`).

Answer (score 1):

[Fancybox API](http://fancybox.net/api)

```
$("#link").fancybox({"showCloseButton": false});
```

Данное действие скроет кнопку закрытия окна.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - скрыть после генерации окна :)

Comment: А можно поподробнее как это сделать? ))